# String Converted in To NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a string like 31-12-1990 . I want to get day ,month,year from this string in iOS7.Please help i m stuck.I m using in iOS8. It work fine bit it give nulll in iOS7.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateofBirth];
```

Comment: You need a date format that actually matches the format of the string. Your string doesn't have slashes, it has dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I set my Deployment Target to 7.0 and ran the following code:

```
NSString *dateofBirth = @"31-12-1990";
NSDate *date;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateofBirth];

NSLog(@"DATE:%@",date);
```

and I'm logging

```
"DATE:1990-12-31 05:00:00 +0000"
```

Can you put the rest of your code?